# ProgressIndicatior is not initialized

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, progress, progress-indicator

In MainPage I have one button. When user clicks on that button, I'm initializing the progress indicator variable. But it is not initializing and it showing null while debugging.
So, how should we show Progress Indicator in windows phone 8 for some task.

Below is my code.

```
ProgressIndicator pi;

private void search_button_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pi = Microsoft.Phone.Shell.SystemTray.ProgressIndicator;
    //Show the indicator
    pi.IsVisible = true;//Here I'm getting null reference exception

    ........here the code for download xml file by calling web service............
}
```

I don't understand why Progress Indicator variable is not initializing.

Comment: It's always null. You need to create and set it.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this ...

```
        private void ShowProgressIndicator(String msg)
        {
            if (ProgressIndicator == null)
            {
                ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
                ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
            }

            ProgressIndicator.Text = msg;
            ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, ProgressIndicator);
        }


        private void HideProgressIndicator()
        {
            ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, ProgressIndicator);
        }
```

and then in your button click

```
private void search_button_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ShowProgressIndicator("Searching");
}
```

i hope this might help you .....